# Windows 10 portable - performance and limitations

Tags: windows-10, portable-apps, windows-to-go

I am considering using [Windows 10 portable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48127) from a fast 64GB USB 3.0 stick, 200MB/s r/w.

1. Should I expect any performance degradation besides my internal SATA SSD to external USB stick degradation.
2. Are there any usage restrictions for this portable configuration, like problems with working on domain, using hyper-v or similar?

Answer (score 3):

I used Rufus to create WinToGo installation on a external HDD/SSD and this works fine. It is a normal Windows 10 (rufus also allows you Home/Pro SKUs to be used). In Windows 8, the upgrade to 8.1 was blocked for WinToGo drives. Maybe this also happens for Windows 10. I never tried updating a build (1511 - Build 10586 to 1607 -Build 14393), so maybe this applies here, too.

I'm able to install desktop programs and they work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Limitation that is sure to happen is the life of your hardware. Surely your pendrive won't last as it use to be because of contimous transfer taking place every second. Moreover it will also put stress on RAM when used for a long time.

Comment: Good thing to consider, i will check specs to know what can I expect. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

So one thing to consider is that even many "fast USB sticks" do not have controllers that are anywhere near as good for random I/O operations as SSDs (or even HDDs for that mattter).  This may or may not matter for your particular workload but there are certainly SOME "200MB/s" USB thumb drives that have such bad random read/write performance that they are very noticeably bad when used as boot drives.  There are also (as HN Singh points out) reliability issues with a lot of flash drives - entirely possible that what you have isn't susceptible to this but it's worth pointing out again.

All that said, I've done what you describe using a Samsung EVO 840 SSD, with a "regular" USB 3.0<->SATA adapter.  I wasn't able to notice any meaningful difference in normal usage compared to having the drive installed natively, except for a small reduction in some of the synthetic benchmarks.  I also created this as a WinToGo system, and I basically use it to carry around a "known installation" of windows 10 to run on whatever other random hardware I happen to be near.  For me, it works great.

Based on your question, I also quickly used this config as a boot drive for a guest machine under Ubuntu 16.04/KVM/qemu -- in this case the fact that the machine was booted from a USB/SATA adapted drive didn't seem to matter either.  The performance seemed no different than booting the "regular" windows VM image from the host machine's local storage.

it's difficult to specifically answer your questions, but hopefully that helps at least some.